# ORACLE APEX LOG MANAGEMENT

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am researching APEX LOGS. And I have 2 questions:

1.)In  "apex_workspace_activity_log " in the column "page_view_type" there are 5 different type :
Processing,
Logout,
Ajax,
Authentication Callback,
Rendering

Can anyone tell me, what means these types (pls :one by one ) ? What should I understand from this Column.

2.) Which log/Where should I look, when I would like to learn DML (update, insert, delete) operations in the Applications. How can i differ from each other the "select" and "DML" logs ?

Thanks in Advance for your Support and Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enabled in your Oracle APEX applications by default, and inserts a record in a log table every time APEX renders a page, or a dynamic action interacting with the database thanks to a PL/SQL or Refresh action.

**Every time a user opens a page, you know when, who, what, why, and how long it took to generate.**

The answers for the **WHY** questions are:

- Ajax: Asynchronous JavaScript and XML action by a user
- Logout: User
  has logged out.
- Processing: User has started/triggered a process.
  ....etc.

So it describes a specific action that the user did.

Comment: Thank you for the Comment. And Can you please answer, What ist "Authentication Callback" ? What should I understand when I see this log ?

Comment: Authentication callback is a Web API to authenticate your end-users. Authlete calls the Web API when end-user authentication is needed.So when you see that in the log it must be there because it has just happened. Approve the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer.